# Inserting into two table simultaneously using hibernate save

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a DTO whose reference table is table_1 and its have has an element collection from table_2 using

@CollectionTable(name="***_***", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="***_*__**"))

I defined it this way because when updating table_1 i want to update table_2 too.

I defined all the procedures and everything correctly.

Can anyone help me in this regard,
Any help is thankful.

Comment: When i save session.save(profile). I want it to update both tables. While it was updating only one table. So i want to know any standard procedure(which I need it to be very secure) for this.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way would be to use `@OneToMany` ([as described in the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-mapping)).

If you add elements to the collection, Hibernate will automatically persist these if you save `table_1`